# passing a parameter from a ImageButton to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

**EDITED QUESTION**

I want to pass a variable, in this case 'name' containing the string bill, to a code behind method and use debug.print to see it

```
string name = "bill";
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="DeleteButton"  ImageUrl="Images/delete.jpg" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name") %>' CommandName="ThisBtnClick" text="Delete Me" onclick="DeleteMonth" />
```

I've tried:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name") %>'
CommandArgument='<%# Bind("name") %>'
CommandArgument='<%= "name" %>
```

This is my print function

```
protected void DeleteMonth(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
      switch (btn.CommandName)
    {
        case "ThisBtnClick":
            Debug.Print("--" + btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
            break;
        case "ThatBtnClick":
            break;
    }
}
```

I think i need to databind something first but honestly I have no idea. I just get a blank when i print. Has anyone dealt with this before

**EDIT**

What I want to do is dynamically create a table. the name variable gets pulled from a database and then creates a table based on that name. I want the last column of the table to be an X so i can delete everything in that row. I'm using an imagebutton. here's my code

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Archive";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string name, created, 1Updated, 2Updated, 3Updated;
            name = rdr.GetString(1);                    // name of month
            if (!(rdr.IsDBNull(2)))                     // checks date for a null value
            { created = rdr.GetDateTime(2).ToString(); }// if not null date is turned into a string and saved in a variable
            else
            { created = "---"; }                        // else date is given a default value
            if (!(rdr.IsDBNull(3)))
            { 1Updated = rdr.GetDateTime(3).ToString(); }
            else
            { 1Updated = "---"; }
            if (!(rdr.IsDBNull(4)))
            { 2Updated = rdr.GetDateTime(4).ToString(); }
            else
            { 2Updated = "---"; }
            if (!(rdr.IsDBNull(5)))
            { 3Updated = rdr.GetDateTime(5).ToString(); }
            else
            { 3Updated = "---"; }

            Response.Write("<tr><td>" + name + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + created + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + 1Updated + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + 2Updated + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + 3Updated + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td><a>1</a></td>");
            Response.Write("<td><a>2</a></td>");
            Response.Write("<td><a>3</a></td>");
            Response.Write("<td><a>Compliance Summary</a></td>");

            Response.Write("<td align = 'center'>"+name);%> 
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="DeleteButton"  ImageUrl="Images/delete.jpg" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name") %>' CommandName="ThisBtnClick" text="Delete Me" onclick="DeleteMonth" /> 
            <% Response.Write("</td></tr>");
        }
```

Comment: Try, DeleteButton.CommandArgument=name; in Page_Load.

Answer (score 3):

Use like this......

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="DeleteButton"  ImageUrl="Images/delete.jpg"      
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName")%>' text="Delete Me" onclick="DeleteMonth" />

 protected void DeleteMonth(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

**ImageButton btn = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;** 
  switch (btn.ToString()) 
  { 
        case "ThisBtnClick": 
            Debug.Print("--" + btn.CommandArgument.ToString()); 
            break; 
        case "ThatBtnClick": 
            break; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: The <%# Eval("UserName")%> does not work. when carried forward to the code behind nothing at all prints... just the hardcoded '--'

Answer (score 1):

Use `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("name")%>'`

instead of `CommandArgument="<%Response.Write(name);%>"`

**EDIT**

Aren't you using Data control like GridView, FormView or DataList? if not you have to use one of those in order to use Eval method. As a example of GridView you have to bind GridView datasource first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx

**OR**

Declare public properties for your DB fields.
[How can I use Eval in asp.net to read fields from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347173/how-can-i-use-eval-in-asp-net-to-read-fields-from-a-database)

The Eval method takes the name of a data field and returns a string containing the value of that field from the current record in the data source.

Comment: Its just showing a blank. Do i need to do something before i use Eval